# Paypal API, What are its capabilities?

Tags: paypal

Well I asked though the paypal site, but have got no answer. I got the famous email with "Your question has been received. To review the status of your ticket, click on the link below." with no link in it. So I'm hoping I can get an answer here.

This is what I sent them:

It appears you have multiple APIs available and I'm having a hard time figuring out what the each API is capable of doing exactly. I want to create a site that in short, brings buyers and seller together. Here is what I am looking for:

1. Buyer and Seller make an agreement through site.
2. Buyer sends money, seller is unable to touch it yet though. (Basically can paypal secure a payment?)
3. Seller gets notice of money sent and notice to ship product ship product.

Alternative paths for step 4:

- Buyer gets product and there are no issues, the buyer confirms the transaction and payment is released to the seller and a set % is sent to me. (Can paypal split payments?)
- Seller never ships product or problem arise in shipping that cannot be resolved, paypal returns money to buyer without penalty. (Can paypal return funds without penalty?)
- Product arrives, but has issues. There will be set penalties for said issues. Penalities are returned to the buyer, then rest is sent to seller and set % sent to me. (can paypal enact a penalty?)

Any general information or answers to my specific questions would be greatly appreciated. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, since you're the service provider, you'll be liable for product delivery.  Paypal won't do it for you.

An ideal workflow would be:

1. Your buyers pay you
2. You withold the payment
3. Buyer okays the shipment
4. You keep your cut and pay the rest to the seller

If you have to refund your buyer (order cancellation, or some other reason), you can use paypal's [refund api](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment/)

To summarize, paypal is just a payment processor and would ensure that payment reaches from endpoint A to endpoint B.  How you use paypal for your particular use cases is totally upto you.

Comment: Doing that way wouldn't paypal get a % cut twice on the same money?

Comment: Thats not even an option, 6% fee automatically plus w/e I would want to get....

I dont understand, how do things like auction sites work? I mean they can't have buyer send money directly to the seller, or they wouldn't get their cut, so are they all getting double charged?